# 'Fixed' Unity - Delete Tilemap tiles one by one with a delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to get the tiles of a Tilemap and I could get them with this code that I found in another question:

```
    BoundsInt bounds = Lvl1.cellBounds;
    TileBase[] allTiles = Lvl1.GetTilesBlock(bounds);

    for (int x = 0; x < bounds.size.x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bounds.size.y; y++)
        {
            TileBase tile = allTiles[x + y * bounds.size.x];
            if (tile != null)
            {
                Lvl1.SetTile(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0), null);
                StartCoroutine(BreakDelay());
            }
            else
            {
                //Debug.Log("x:" + x + " y:" + y + " tile: (null)");
            }
        }
    }
```

But now I want to delete every tile logged one by one with a Delay of '0.1f' for example. I have been trying many ways that didnt work as I wanted so i gave up, then I'd remember StackOverflock and now im here trying to get some help, so does anybody know the solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> StartCoroutine(BreakDelay());
> ```

This is not how coroutines work.

This *starts the execution of* a coroutine (which may pause at any time) but does *not* pause the execution of *the caller.*

If you want your current code to wait, you need to make *it* the coroutine:

```
StartCoroutine(DeleteTiles());

...

private IEnumerator DeleteTiles() {
    BoundsInt bounds = Lvl1.cellBounds;
    TileBase[] allTiles = Lvl1.GetTilesBlock(bounds);

    for (int x = 0; x < bounds.size.x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < bounds.size.y; y++)
        {
            TileBase tile = allTiles[x + y * bounds.size.x];
            if (tile != null)
            {
                Lvl1.SetTile(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0), null);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); //or however long
            }
            else
            {
                //Debug.Log("x:" + x + " y:" + y + " tile: (null)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so I found that the map isnt deleting in the correct position https://imgur.com/rCL00t6.png, im gonna fix it and tell you if it works!

Comment: Glad you fixed that, as I have no idea. I just copied your code. :P